# Angular 5 - Angular service doesn't show data in the `Modal`

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-services

I am using a component and service to work with modals in my application.
In `download.compoment.ts` I have a method that opens the modal window.

**download.component.ts**

```js
constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

public openModalProperty(id: string, nameFile: string) {
    this.properties = [];
    this.propertyService.byFile(+id).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.properties = data;
            if (this.properties && this.properties.length > 0) {
                this.titleFile = nameFile;
                this.openModal("modal-download");
            } else {
                this.showErrorProperties(this.titleFile);
            }
        },
        _ => {
            this.processError();
        }
    );
}

public openModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.open(id);
}
```

`properties` is an array of `object`, whose data is displayed in a modal window.
The template is as follows:

**download.component.html**

```html
<app-modal id="modal-download" [title]="titleFile">
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let property of properties">
        <label>{{ property.name }}: &nbsp; </label><label> {{ property.value }} 
        </label>
    </div>
</app-modal>
```

In `localhost` it works perfectly, I click on the `button` and it shows the `modal` with the corresponding data, but nevertheless when I upload it to production the modal window opens, but the information of the property arrangement is not displayed or only when I press any key on the keyboard or click on mouse it loads the information.

What could be happened?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like there is a change detection problem, do you have any of your components `OnPush`?  Maybe try to manual `check for changes` after modal opened?

Comment: I don't have OnPush, but I don't know what manually checking changes means :(

Comment: Probably is not the case, but: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/. Still worth learning. 

Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, I don't get any error, the modal opens, the modal appears empty, but pressing any key displays the information.

Comment: To be sure that `detection` is not the problem, add `cdr` as `ChangeDetectionRef` in your constructor as dependency in your component and then add `setTimeout(() => this.cdr.detectChanges())` after  ` this.modalService.open(id);`.

Comment: Ohh with your last indications it seems that it works perfect, thank you very much, as it is random I will test several times, but everything seems to be correct :).

Comment: For educational reasons I will try to explain, You trigger the modal service and that opens the modal. The modal is opening but it hasn't triggered the change detection with the values because the values changed before the instance of the modal is been created. That's the reason that after a left or right click everything workes fine. It's because you triggered the component to check detection by doing that clicked and detection goes for all the child components by the component triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that detection is not the problem, add `cdr` as `ChangeDetectionRef` in your constructor as dependency in your component and then add `setTimeout(() => this.cdr.detectChanges())` after `this.modalService.open(id);`

For educational reasons I will try to explain.

You trigger the modal service and that opens the modal.

The modal is opening but it hasn't triggered the change detection with the values because the values changed before the instance of the modal is been created.

That's the reason that after a left or right click everything works fine. It's because you triggered the component to check detection by doing that clicked and detection goes for all the child components by the component triggered.

*I posted my comments here, because it seems to be the right answer.*

Comment: Definitely the solution is correct, I am testing and everything is fine.